# How to optimize a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER T 
ON TABLE_2 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
     DECLARE @bought_t int,
             @name_t varchar(20)

     SELECT @name_t = name_t 
     FROM inserted

     SELECT @bought_t = bought_t 
     FROM TABLE_1 
     WHERE name_t = @name_t

     IF @bought_t < 100 
     BEGIN
         UPDATE TABLE_1
         SET bought_t = @bought_t + 1
         WHERE TABLE_1.name_t = @name_t
     END
     ELSE 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

The column (`TABLE_1`) I'm making the update to after the insert happens in the 'TABLE_2' is supposed to hold values between 50 and 100. So I'm asking If this trigger is as professional and optimized as It could be? or I have some flaws that could lead to bugs/security issues.

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @name_t = name_t FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: How do you know it is in a transaction?  Using `else rollback` will throw an error if the trigger ever runs the `rollback` code when the `insert into` TABLE_2 didn't start with a transaction.  Also, how do you know what else will be rolled back.  If anyone else ever writes code, will they realize why their changes are being rolled back when the `bought_t` value is >= 100?  And, it's impossible to say if it is optimized without a lot more information.  For starters, you should simply run the `update` statement from the trigger in SSMS and capture the query plan.  That should tell you a lot.

Comment: @marc_s Indeed. I just tried this (random values)
`INSERT INTO TABLE_2 VALUES('A','B'), 
('B','Z'), 
('S','A'), 
('A','S'), 
('D','G')`
and I got the update function running once only.

Comment: @JamesL. I believe, there is a lot to learn. what is the definition of `transaction` in this case? and what would be the alternative for `rollback`? I indeed saw the error message popping up, Is there is any way to avoid it If I don't want users to put values greater then 100 ?

Comment: @JamesL.: inside a trigger, you're ***always*** in a transaction - either in one that you've defined *explicitly*, or if that's not the case, then you're inside an *implicit* transaction for your statement.

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @JamesL.: the `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` is the only way inside a trigger to stop the transaction / operation that caused this trigger to fire. However: this doesn't mean that the trigger "does nothing" - it actually **aborts** (and rolls back) the operation, so that's really the "sledgehammer" approach to stopping whatever is happening. And if you have an `INSERT` with 50 rows, you cannot selectively rollback 20 of those inserts and let the other 30 go - it's an all-or-nothing way, either you **STOP** the operation (all of it), or not....

Comment: @marc_s - the OP needs to explain what they are really trying to accomplish.  I suspect a `rollback` isn't quite it.

Comment: @JamesL. I simply don't want it to update anywhere above 100 so basically the trigger shouldn't launch/work unless the value is less then 100.

Comment: @user3832856: that's what my solution is doing - if the value is less than 100, update - if it's 100 or more - just ignore. No need for a `ROLLBACK` here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to completely rewrite your trigger to be **set-based** and to be able to work with **multiple rows** in the `Inserted` pseudo table.

Fortunately, that also makes it easier - in my opinion - try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T 
ON TABLE_2 
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    UPDATE T1
    SET bought_t = bought_t + 1
    FROM TABLE_1 T1
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.name_t = T1.name_t
    WHERE T1.bought_t < 100
```

**UPDATE:** demo to prove this works:

```
-- create the two tables
CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), ProdName VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (ProdName VARCHAR(50), Bought INT)
GO

-- create trigger on "TABLE_2" to update "TABLE_1"    
CREATE TRIGGER T2Insert
ON TABLE_2
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE T1
    SET Bought = Bought + 1
    FROM TABLE_1 T1
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON T1.ProdName = i.ProdName
    WHERE T1.Bought < 100
GO

-- initialize TABLE_1 with some seed data
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE_1 (ProdName, Bought)
VALUES ( 'Prod1', 0), ('Prod2', 20), ('Prod3', 40), ('Prod4', 40), ('Prod100', 100)

-- insert new values into TABLE_2
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE_2 (ProdName)
VALUES  ('Prod1'), ('Prod100'), ('Prod2'), ('Prod4')

-- get data to check
SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE_1
```

This renders output:

[image]

As you can easily see:

- Prod1, Prod2, Prod4 that were inserted caused an update of the value `Bought`
- Prod100 which was also inserted did **not** cause an update of `Bought`

**UPDATE #2:** if you need to be able to insert multiple identical values at once, you need to slightly enhance your trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T2Insert
ON TABLE_2
AFTER INSERT
AS
    -- declare table variable to hold names and update counts 
    DECLARE @UpdateCount TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50), UpdCount INT)

    -- from the "Inserted" table, determine which names are being
    -- inserted how many times using GROUP BY    
    INSERT INTO @UpdateCount (Name, UpdCount)
        SELECT ProdName, COUNT(*)
        FROM Inserted
        GROUP BY ProdName

    -- now join to this temporary table, and update as many times
    -- as needed (instead of +1 for all cases)
    UPDATE T1
    SET Bought = Bought + uc.UpdCount
    FROM TABLE_1 T1
    INNER JOIN @UpdateCount uc ON uc.Name = T1.ProdName
    WHERE T1.Bought < 100
GO
```

Comment: Shouldn't `@bought_t` simply be `bought_t`?

Comment: @JamesL.: yes - of course - copy&paste error - fixed, thanks!

Comment: This still result in having an update once only. If I insert the values given in the comment above, I get:
`(1 row(s) affected)
(5 row(s) affected)` so the trigger only updated once instead of 5

Comment: @user3832856: the `1 row affected` is for the `INSERT` statement into `TABLE_2`, while the second message `5 rows affected` is the **TRIGGER** updating five rows (so it updated `TABLE_1` for **all** of the inserted rows)

Comment: Are you sure? because my code was doing the same thing (same results). and If I check the table, I see that It only got +1 instead of +5 .

Comment: @marc_s Just to confirm, I tried to run on a value that already have 100. The return was '0 rows affected' and '5 rows affected'. So I believe the first row = the update which is 1 in the first example and the second row is 5 (the insert statements) so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the EDIT. Its still weird though. The trigger is actually functioning when I made a WHILE loop to insert data but still not working with that INSERT METHOD I posted/ you gave example with. Any thoughts?

Comment: @marc_s  Your code have the same issue as me. Try to insert multiple same values like this `INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE_2 (ProdName)
VALUES  ('Prod1'), ('Prod1'), ('Prod1')` Its going to update once only.

Comment: @user3832856: I guess if you insert the same value multiple times, the trigger will always go "back" to the original table value (that exist before the `INSERT` started) and increment by one. Basically, it would "miss" that multiple identical values are being inserted. If you need to really support this, you'd have to do a `GROUP BY` on the `Inserted` table and determine the number of entries for each value in the insert, and then apply those values (instead of `+ 1`) in the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: @marc_s Works fine! thanks! I believe that the same concept applies for AFTER UPDATE and AFTER DELETE  triggers?

Comment: @user3832856: yes, absolutely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144119/discussion-between-user3832856-and-marc-s).

Comment: @marc_s I was using your example, do you have an idea about this [Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954693/executing-a-trigger) ?